# In Unity VoiceReq, how do I get an error if the PhraseRecognizer fails to identify anything?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voice-recognition

This is the basic code that I have. I need to get an error when the phrase isn't recognized so that I can broadcast a msg to the fungus flow chart and make response off this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
using System.Linq;
using Fungus;

public class VoiceReq : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    //KeywordRecognizer keyRec;
    public Flowchart flowchart;
    Dictionary<string, System.Action> keyWord = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();
    PhraseRecognizer keyRec;
    public void Start()
    {
        keyWord = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();

        ConfidenceLevel confidence = ConfidenceLevel.Low;
        string lvl = "low";
        //flowchart.GetStringVariable("lvl");
        if (lvl == "high")
        {
            confidence = ConfidenceLevel.Low;        
        }
        if (lvl == "medium")        
        {
            confidence = ConfidenceLevel.Medium;        
        }
        if (lvl == "high")        
        {
            confidence = ConfidenceLevel.High;        
        }

        //Waiter greetings and other interactions//
        //GreetingStart
        //GS1
        keyWord.Add("How are you", () =>
        {
            GS();        
        });
        //GS2
        keyWord.Add("How's it going", () =>
        {
            GS();        
        });
        keyRec = new KeywordRecognizer(keyWord.Keys.ToArray(),confidence);
        keyRec.OnPhraseRecognized += KeywordRecognizerOnPhraseRecognized;
        keyRec.Start();
    }
    void KeywordRecognizerOnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("Keyword on phrase Rec");
        System.Action keyWordAction;
        if (keyWord.TryGetValue(args.text, out keyWordAction))
        {
            keyWordAction.Invoke();
        }
    }
    void CheckIfFound(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Action keyWordAction;
        if (keyWord.TryGetValue(args.text, out keyWordAction))
        {
            keyWordAction.Invoke();
        }
    }

    //GreetingStart
    void GS()
    {
        Flowchart.BroadcastFungusMessage("GS");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but did you try it here `if (keyWord.TryGetValue(args.text, out keyWordAction)) { ... } else { YOUR ERROR CODE }`?

Comment: Yea i tried that still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry I had a closer look now and `OnPhraseRecognized` is ofcourse only called if a phrase was already recognized. So my earlier suggestion of ofcourse makes no sense if you want an error when a phrase was not recognized.

Comment: You could have a look at the [Dictation recognizer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.DictationRecognizer.html) instead. It has more events such as `DictationResult` and `DictationError`. This should give you the expected control.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: hay thanks I'll give that a try and will read the link thanks for the help, if that doesnt work ill just find a work around